# trying to use Amazon S3 on Ggost running on Heroku to store all the images on it instead of storing them locally

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ghost

I've been trying to set up Ghost storage adapter S3 on my 1.7 ghost installation, but I must to be missing something on the way. I created a bucket with policies what are allowing access to IAM user previously created and with AmazonS3FullAccess permissions, so far so good, Ive got added the lines into config.production.json with AccessKey and secretkey from IAM as [readme](https://github.com/colinmeinke/ghost-storage-adapter-s3) says but its not working properly. I attach a report screen from heroku logs[image: heroku logs]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find how to fix it on 1.7 version but after updating Ghost to 1.21.1 it's working right.